# How to disable the last row 2nd column onclick & give an alert message

Tags: php, jquery

I have made this page for booking where i have a form opening on click a form opens.But now on click of 2nd column of last row i don't want that form to be open instead i want an alert box. Please help.

```
<html><head><title>MRA</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".showAlert").click(function(){
   alert("You cannot select this time slot"); 
    });
   var $index;
   var systemdate = new Date();
   $('.meeting-error').hide();
   $(".meeting-timetable tr > td + td").click(function(e) {
   if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('The selected time slot has already been assigned');
   } else {
   var $thisVal = $(this).prevAll('td:first-child').text();     
   var hour=$thisVal.substr(0,2);
   var min=$thisVal.substr(3,3);   
   var d = new Date ("<?php print $selecteddate; ?>");
   var n = d.getFullYear();
   var m = d.getDate();
   var k = d.getMonth();
   var userdate=new Date(n,k,m,hour,min,0);
   if( systemdate > userdate )
   {
     alert("Select Time Slot greater than the Current Time");
     return;    
   }
</script>
</head>
<body background="a6.jpg">
<table class="meeting-timetable" border="1" ">
<tr><th id="td" colspan="2" class="calender-date" align="center"><?php print  
$selecteddate; ?></th></tr>
<tr><td id="08:00:00" align="center">08:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="08:30:00" align="center">08:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="09:00:00" align="center">09:00</td><td class="showAlert"  
id="td"></td></tr>
</table>
<form align="center" method="post" id="inform">
<h1 align="center">Meeting Details</h1>
<table>
<tr><td><b>Room : </td><td><input type="text" value="Meeting Room" readonly>   
</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Name :</td><td><input type="text" readonly value="Ankit"</td>   
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>   
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML? And what have you tried?

Comment: This is just a part of the code .What i want exactly is on click of 2 column of last row an alert box should be displayed.

Comment: I tried this code $(".showAlert").click(function(){
       alert("You cannot select this time slot"); 
}); & gave that particular row this class it gave an alert box but on click of ok of alert box it showed the form which i don't want.

Comment: You really need to use some indentations.

Comment: I dont think anyone will go through this code untill it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to understand your codes, here is an example that helps you to achieve this:

```
$('table tr td').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var _cellIndex = $(this)[0].cellIndex;
    var _rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
    var total_row = $('table tr').length - 1;

    // Match Last row and 2nd column
    if( _rowIndex ==  total_row && _cellIndex == 1 ) {
        // Apply your Design and alert
        alert('Disabled');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/dafc5ptu/)

**UPDATE:** After getting the fiddle this is what i have implemented in your fiddle:

```
var _cellIndex = $(this)[0].cellIndex;
var _rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
var total_row = $('.meeting-timetable tr').length - 1;
if( _rowIndex ==  total_row && _cellIndex == 1 ) {
    alert('You cannot select this time slot');
}
else $('#plan, #plan-bg').fadeIn();
```

This is the [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/q37b07nx/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the help.But i modified my code & added a class to that particular <td> itself.It gives an alert box but on click of OK button the form appears. I don't want that form on click of Ok of alert box.

Comment: @Ankit i checked your JS, you don't need to add `$(".showAlert").click(function(){`, just check the on the main click event when you open box, or Provide a working fiddle and i will help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kansara_Ankit/q37b07nx/ This is the interface & code.Please check.In this on click of td next to time given a form appears where the user needs to fill the details.But on click of last row td i want an alert box & form shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: @Ankit link for? I have updated your fiddle and linked to **working fiddle** in my answer.